# Using SuperLU sparse solver with RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to use the SparseLU solver from armadillo (http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve) through RcppArmadillo:

```
#define ARMA_USE_SUPERLU
// [Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec sp_solver(arma::sp_mat K, arma::vec x) {
  arma::superlu_opts opts;
  opts.symmetric = true;
  arma::vec res;
  arma::spsolve(res, K, x, "superlu", opts);
  return res;
}

/*** R
library(Matrix)
K <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 2, 1), j = c(1, 2, 2), x = c(1, 1, 0.5), symmetric = TRUE)
x <- runif(2)
sp_solver(K, x)
*/
```

I get the error `undefined reference to 'superlu_free'`. 
I guess I'm missing some library linking.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

---

I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RcppArmadillo is *super-convenient* and I use it myself *all the time*. Because *all* Rcpp* code is going to be called from R, we can assume *some* functionality to be present.

This includes LAPACK and BLAS, and explains why we can use RcppArmadillo "without linking" even when the Armadillo documentation *clearly* states you need LAPACK and BLAS.  Why?  Well *because R already has LAPACK and BLAS*.

(As an aside, this lead to considerable early issues if and only if R was built with its own subset of LAPACK as certain complex valued routines were not available. Baptiste was hit quite a bit by this as his packages need(ed) these. Over the years, Brian Ripley was most helpful in adding those missing routines to R's LAPACK.  And one never had issues when R was built with an external LAPACK and BLAS as is common for *e.g.* the Debian/Ubuntu package I maintain.)

Here you want SuperLU. This is optional, and it is *your job* to ensure this gets linked.  In short, it does *not* just work magically.  And it is hard to automate as it involves linking which gets us platform-dependendy and installation requirements we cannot control for easily.

But the question is not new, and there is in fact [an entire Rcpp Gallery post](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-with-superlu/) on the topic.

*Edit:* And with one-liner from that post that is suitable for my system, your code works just fine too (once I correct the `Rcpp::depends` to have the double brackets it needs:

```
R> Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lsuperlu")
R> sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

R> library(Matrix)

R> K <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 2, 1), j = c(1, 2, 2), x = c(1, 1, 0.5), symmetric = TRUE)

R> x <- runif(2)

R> sp_solver(K, x)
         [,1]
[1,] 0.264929
[2,] 0.546050
R>
```

#### Corrected Code

```
#define ARMA_USE_SUPERLU
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec sp_solver(arma::sp_mat K, arma::vec x) {
  arma::superlu_opts opts;
  opts.symmetric = true;
  arma::vec res;
  arma::spsolve(res, K, x, "superlu", opts);
  return res;
}

/*** R
library(Matrix)
K <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 2, 1), j = c(1, 2, 2), x = c(1, 1, 0.5), symmetric = TRUE)
x <- runif(2)
sp_solver(K, x)
*/
```